# CartoDb single marker cartodb.js

Tags: carto, url

Im looking for a way to add a marker on a position that is not in a database using cartodb.js.

Something similar to this in Mapbox would be great:

```
L.mapbox.featureLayer({
    // this feature is in the GeoJSON format: see geojson.org
    // for the full specification
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        // coordinates here are in longitude, latitude order because
        // x, y is the standard for GeoJSON and many formats
        coordinates: [
          -77.03221142292,
          38.913371603574 
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Leaflet for this, an example:

```
cartodb.createVis('map', VIZ_JSON_HERE)
        .done(function(vis, layers) {
          map = vis.getNativeMap();
          L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
        })
        .error(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

The Leaflet library is included directly when you include CartoDB.js, so you won't need to worry about that :-)

If you're interested on how to customize those markers I recommend you to take a look here: http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html